# How to prevent XJC to generate javadoc header comments?

Tags: xjc

I use XJC to generate some Java classes, but the generated Java code contains ugly Javadoc headers.

Example:

```
/**
 * <p> Java class for XXX complex type.
   ....
 */
```

How do I tell XJC to not generate this?

I tried `-no-header` option, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

That's not a header, that's a Javadoc comment on the class itself.

`-no-header` removes the following style from the *very top* of the file

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.4-2 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2014.03.06 at 06:14:40 PM GMT 
//
```

To remove the comments you have to post-process the file.  This question details how that can be achieved: [JAXB XJC Possible to suppress comment creation in generated classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093514/jaxb-xjc-possible-to-suppress-comment-creation-in-generated-classes)

Answer (score 1):

Please see my detailed answer how to change prolog text (file header comment) in this answer: [JAXB XJC Possible to suppress comment creation in generated classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093514/jaxb-xjc-possible-to-suppress-comment-creation-in-generated-classes/54316869#54316869)

In that particular case in short you may just:

1. Create file `src/main/resources/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/MessageBundle_en.properties`
2. And place in it override:

```
# {0} - name-identifier-format-enum
ClassSelector.JavadocHeading = \
    <p>Java class for {0}.
```

...to customize message in Javadoc.