# JAXB english comments in generated file

Tags: maven, jaxb, xjc

I use XJC to compile some XSD to Java classes. On my machine, instead of the usual comment

```
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.11
```

I get the same comment but in italian

```
// Questo file è stato generato dall'architettura JavaTM per XML Binding (JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.11
```

XJC is invoked with Maven plugin `maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.0:generate`.
Same pom generates different comments on different machines.
How do I switch comments back to English?
I run it on JDK 1.8.0_66 on Windows 10 with Italian locale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify a locale that will be used during generation of the classes, with the help of the [`<locale>`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configuration-Cheat-Sheet) attribute.

> `locale` - Locale used during generation, for instance `en`, `de`, `fr` etc. This will, for instance, influence the language of the generated JavaDoc comments.

By default, `maven-jaxb2-plugin` will use your user locale. [Sample configuration](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Controlling-the-Output) for the plugin would be:

```xml
<configuration>
  <locale>en</locale> <!-- this will use the English locale -->
</configuration>
```