# Workaround to Remove/Ignore JAXB Generated Timestamp

Tags: java, utf-8, ant, jaxb, xjc

I have a requirement to build an eclipse project via ant script that also requires my date/location and system locale to Greek. So, I've come across the error below

```
"unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
    [javac] // Generated on: 2018.09.08 at 12:10:19 ?? CST"
```

This is the exact comment lines from the generated Java class.

```
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.1.5-b01-fcs

// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a>

// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema.

// Generated on: 2018.09.08 at 12:10:19 πμ CST
```

With my research from the past few days, I learned that the timestamp has a prepared format that it sets for its value. So modifying my system date/time format wouldn't work.

All encoding are set to "UTF-8".
Is there a command/property available for use to ignore this specific character during compile?
Because apparently, I'm thinking of a script to be ran to modify the classes and have the comments removed(after generated) so during compile I wouldn't get any errors.

Comment: Since the `xjc` command doesn't have an option to specify the file encoding, and you want your source files to be UTF-8 encoded, you'll need to run a re-encoding program after generating the source files, to change encoding from Greek (ISO-8859-7?) to UTF-8.

Comment: See also: [JAXB XJC Possible to suppress comment creation in generated classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5093514/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer how to customize file header and remove date: [JAXB XJC Possible to suppress comment creation in generated classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093514/jaxb-xjc-possible-to-suppress-comment-creation-in-generated-classes/54316869#54316869) that should resolve your problem.

Also you may just provide correct locale. See related answer [how to make cxf-xjc-plugin generate sources in utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777386/how-to-make-cxf-xjc-plugin-generate-sources-in-utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html). Use **-no-header** and the comment generation will be suppressed completely.